# Android Context#createPackageContext returns incorrect context

Tags: android

I am trying to access the context of another app with a different package name, but the same `sharedId` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Setup
 1. Android Studio Beta 0.8.9
 2. Android SDK level 19
 3. HTC One Development build device
 4. identical android:sharedUserId

When calling `context.createPackageContext(friendAppPackageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);` I confirmed the `friendAppPackageName` is the right one, and different from this context, but the result from the method call always return my own context, which is different from the one I wanted.

My goal is to access the SharedPreferences of the friend app with the same `sharedId`, and signing signature, I am doing the test in debug signing process.

Anything I can do to debug further on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out another device and it seems to be related to write permissions on the shell. My HTC One is a developer build with read-only rom. With a Samsung device, i was able to get the correct context and SharedPreferences.